# MVC 3 and the PartialViews, scripts aren't visible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, partial-views

in my Layout file (I use the Razor syntax) I have included the `jQuery script library`.

In my partialView, I have `jPaginate script library` and the code that generates this plugin. The problem is, in that scenario that plugin is not being rendered, but if I move the `jQuery script library` to the PartialView, it works. But I can't move the `jQuery script library` from the Layout.

> So, how to access the scripts included in the Layout page in the
>   PartialView ?

Or maybe there is other solution ?

---

the code:

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
     @RenderBody()

     @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
```

**MyView.cshtml**

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("SomeAction", "MyContoller"); } //it outputs the PartialView.vshtml

    @section Scripts {
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.paginate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#pages").paginate({
                    count: 12,
                    start: 1,
                    display: 10,
                    border: false,
                    text_color: '#888',
                    background_color: '#EEE',
                    text_hover_color: 'black',
                    background_hover_color: '#CFCFCF'
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

**PartialView.cshtml**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jpaginate.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="pages"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is your jQuery script rendered in the Layout? Is it towards the end of the layout? If this is the case then when you include the plugin in your partial, jQuery is not yet defined. I would recommend you defining a section in your layout towards the end that will contain custom included scripts:

```
<body>
    ...
    ...
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

and then in the view that is using that partial (not in the partial, a partial shouldn't be dealing with any scripts, it should be markup only) override this section to include any plugins this view requires:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/foo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // some inline script that uses the foo plugin
    </script>
}
```

This way all scripts that this page requires will get rendered at the end of the markup which is the recommended approach.

Comment: Darin, please view my edited description, I've included the code

Comment: @Tony, you seem to have hardcoded the location of the paginate helper: `/Scripts/jquery.paginate.js` instead of using a Url helper as you did with the jQuery plugin. This won't work if you deploy your application in a virtual directory in IIS. Other than that your code should work. But as I explained in my answer, partials shouldn't contain any scripts. The best practice is to have all your scripts at the end of the page. That's what YSlow recommends. CSS in the head, markup only in the middle and scripts at the bottom :-).

Comment: OK, but If I move the jPaginate generating script to the `@section Scripts`, then I get the error `$("#pages") is null`

Comment: @Tony, if you put the `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)` at the end of the markup in your layout you no longer need to use `document.ready`.

Comment: I've done that, and also if I remove the `$(function () {}` and get the code outside it, the error remains. If the `$(function () {}` is still used, I don't get the error anymore, but the plugin is still not being generated

Comment: @Tony, the `$('#pages')` jQuery selector cannot possibly return null. jQuery selectors never return null which is what allows you to chain method calls and gives all the power of jQuery. It can return an empty array if no element matches the selector. This might happen if you try to use it before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I've edited again my description, now You can see how it now looks like

Comment: @Tony, you have placed the RenderScripts section outside the body. It should be **inside**. Look at my answer once again.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. But nothing changed

Comment: @Tony, if you send me a sample project illustrating your problem I would be glad to take a look at it and help you. Like this its difficult to understand what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: It's a part of the big project so I'll create a sample project and I'll send it to You if the problem remains.

Comment: @Tony, great narrowing it down would be superb.

Answer (score 2):

If the script for jQuery is after the declaration for the Partial View you will get problems.  I would recommend putting the jQuery script before the `RenderBody`.

Comment: Actually another solution would be to create a new Section (are you using Razor?) for scripts after you include the jQuery script.  Let me know if you need a code sample for clarification...